# Using nginx-ingress http works but https is not on selfhost kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

i use the [nginx-ingress](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/overview/) in my kubernetes cluster

i installed the nginx-ingress-controller successful.
here is my `ingress`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: demo.test.cn
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: demo-service
                port:
                  number: 443
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-node
  ports:
    - port: 443 # service port
      targetPort: 8080 # container port
      protocol: TCP
    # nodePort port exposed on the host machine
```

- pupulate http url [http://demo.test.cn/] in browser, it works well
- populate the https url [https://demo.test.cn/] in browser, it does't work
- check the log in nginx-ingress-controller
  [access log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKCh5.png)

Comment: HTTPS requires certificates, have you configured any?

Comment: Yeah, i configured  certificates.
And when access by https, the nginx-ingress-controller return 404, i am sure the reqeust already arrived the nginx-ingress-controller